# Flask, Heroku, and Templates

Tags: templates, heroku, flask

UPDATE: Unsure why, but after installing loggly in order to get more insight into what's happening, it's now working. I can't fathom why this would be.

My flask webapp works locally using Foreman, however if I use the same test input on heroku, I get an Internal Server Error:

```
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

The logs show almost nothing (that may be a separate question) but using print debugging, I've found that this has to be something to do with rendering the template because everything works up until then. Given that it works locally, it's also then the case that there's not an html error, so it must be something about sourcing the templates.

My structure looks like the following:

```
Procfile
venv
requirements.txt
app
  /templates
    /login.html
    /user_profile.html
    /index.html
  /models
  /views
...
```

If I adjust the structure so that the templates folder is on the same level as Procfile, venv, etc, then no page works, but as it is, both index.html and login.html display just fine.

Any idea what's up? Thanks much.

Comment: You should add an answer to your post and accept it, so people will know that you have an answer that may help them as well. Thanks